# Expected impedance across TX pair and RX pair on a functional RJ45 port

Tags: short-circuit, rj45

I'm using a sensor that has ethernet output. This new sensor is a replacement of yet another same sensor that seemed to have short-circuit like situation between its RX+/- pins.

After connecting the new sensor to my single board computer (SBC) there was no sign of activity/data and I checked the voltage on various pins and observed that the TX+/- pins appear to be having 0.8 Ohm resistance.

[image] ( [source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/206926/connecting-a-rj45-magjack))

The circuit schematic of a magjack ethernet connector shows internal magnetic couplings and they might make the circuit appear like a short-circuit but be functionally normal. I'm confused if the RJ45 communication interface is intact or otherwise.

My question is: **what is the expected resistance between TX+/- pins (and RX+/-) pins in a functional RJ45 socket?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Ethernet transformers seem to be 0.9 ohms max so your 0.8 ohms is within specs.

The trasformer coil is basically a short circuit if you try to measure it with a multimeter.

Comment: Could you please cite a reference datasheet ?